# Python: I have a list of 'wrapped objects' that take a query. How can I print the query to the screen?

Tags: python, api, list, twitter, arguments

I'm using Python and Twitter API. I have a list of searches, and then one is randomly chosen:

```
 search hashtag, and RT latest
p1 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash1")
p2 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash2")
p3 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash3")
p4 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash4")
p5 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash5")
p6 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash6")
p7 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash7")
p8 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash8")
p9 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash9")
p10 = tx.search.tweets(q="#hash10")
px = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10]
p = choice(px)
```

How can I then print the arg 'q's value further down the code?
I've tried print(inspect.getargspec(p)) but it returns an error.

Any insight? I literally just want the output:

> "#hash7"

if p7 was the choice from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search after you pick a key:

```
keys = ["#hash{}".format(i) for i in range(1,11)]
p_key = choice(keys)
p = tx.search.tweets(q=p_key)
```

Or, if you still want all the search results, make a dictionary:

```
ps = {key : tx.search.tweets(q=key) for key in keys}
p = ps[p_key]
```